# How can I get a coordinate of a button on Windows Security window by Python

Tags: python, winapi, pyautogui

I want pyautogui to press 'OK' button on a 'Windows Security' window on Win10.
I can get a handle of the 'Windows Security' window so far, but I cannot get the handle 'OK' button to get the coordinate.

[image]

Following is a code but it does not work...

```
count = 0
child_list = []

def add_to_list(hwnd, param):
    if win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) == 'OK':
        print('add button')
        child_list.append(hwnd)
        
        
time.sleep(5)

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Windows Security")

print(f'handle: {hwnd}')    # <- got actual handl value.

win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, add_to_list, None)

print(len(child_list))    # <- got 0. nothing in the list.

rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(child_list[0])
x = (rect[0]+rect[2])/2
y = (rect[1]+rect[3])/2
print(x, y)
```

Could you please give me any clue please.
Thank you,

**UPDATE**

I used pywinauto with Chrome displaying login dialog as below. Thank you for your comment!

[image]

```
mywindow = Desktop(backend='uia')["ログイン"]
mywindow.print_control_identifiers()
```

It showed successfully identifiers about the dialog as below, which means that "ログイン" is working.

```
   |    |    | Edit - 'ユーザー名'    (L391, T188, R743, B224)
   |    |    | ['ユーザー名Edit', 'Edit', 'Edit0', 'Edit1']
   |    |    | child_window(title="ユーザー名", control_type="Edit")
```

But I do know how to set name and pw. Following did not work.

```
mywindow.WindowName['ユーザー名Edit'].set_text('Bob')
```

Also, following did not.

```
exe = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe'
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path=exe)
print(app['Login'].exists())
```

.exists() returned 'False'. How can I set name to the text box?
Thank you,

Comment: Use [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with the `uia` backend, and you won't have to fiddle with coordinates of buttons you cannot get to anyway. There is no `HWND` backing that button after all.

Comment: I edited my original question about pywinauto.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mywindow.Edit.set_text('Bob')`. You can refer to *pywinauto: How to know magic attribute names* And I have run `mywindow.Button2.click()` successfully which maximizes a new Google Chrome Pane.

Comment: Thank you for checking my code, however your both line made error. 1st code does not specify which text box you want to fill with 'Bob'. I found another way to send name and pw by chrome auto authentication feature and it worked as below.
asis: driver.get('https://www.sample.com')
tobe: driver.get('https://username:password@www.sample.com')